# Is there a Snowflake equivalent for T-SQL INSERT INTO [Tablename] EXEC [StoredProcedure]?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using T-SQL in SQL Server I can insert the results of a stored procedure into a table using this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO <TableName> 
EXEC <StoredProcedureName>
GO
```

Presently there is already a Stored Procedure that returns the data I need so I'd rather not re-invent the existing query to get that data into a table; but I'm not that knowledgeable with the capabilities of Snowflake in this respect.

Is there a similar Snowflake syntax I could use to achieve the same result?

The closest I could find was the Copy Into command but I haven't been able to successfully use it in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) to operate on stored procedure output:

```
CALL <stored_procedure>;

INSERT INTO <table_name>(....)
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

---

Sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(i INT);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dummy()
RETURNS TABLE(col INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
 DECLARE
        res RESULTSET default (select 1 AS c);
  BEGIN
        RETURN TABLE(res);
  END;
$$;

CALL dummy();


INSERT INTO t(i)
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

SELECT * FROM t;
-- i
-- 1
```

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. I did notice that the call returned data to the console before it inserted it into the table. Is there anyway to prevent the data from being returned prior to inserting it into the table? Just wondering b/c I think this may be a problem with stored procedures that return a large quantity of data by requiring 2 trips. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mark I am not aware of a way to discard a resultset in a CALL and later being able to use it with RESULT_SCAN.  If you could rework  stored procedure definition then stored procedure could perform INSERT INTO directly inside SP, without returning resultset.